# Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}e^{\frac{x}{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}e^{\frac{x}{n}}$.

Is f differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$?

I can prove  the series does not uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$. But this does not imply f is not differentiable.

Comment: Tty to take the derivative term by term and see what you can say about the resulting series.

Answer (score 5):

Write 
$$ f(x) - f(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} \left( e^{x/n} - 1 \right) $$
Now $e^{x/n} - 1 = x/n + O((x/n)^2)$, and since $\sum_n 1/n^{3/2}$ converges we find that this series converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb C$.  Thus $f(x) - f(0)$ is an entire function, and then so is $f(x)$.

Comment: You sure $f(0)=1$?  Shouldn't it be $-\eta(1/2)$?

Comment: Where do you see $f(0)=1$?  No, $\displaystyle f(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Cheers

Comment: Saying that $f'(z) = z\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^{-3/2} e^{z/n}$ converges absolutely so that $f(z)$ is holomorphic can be easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

> **I thought it might be instructive to present a "brute-force" way forward that relies on straightforward analysis and an inequality for the exponential function.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}}e^{x/n}\right|&=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/2}}e^{x/n}\left(\frac{e^{h/n}-1}{h}-\frac1n\right)\right|\\\\
&\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2}}e^{x/n}\left|\frac{e^{h/n}-1}{h}-\frac1n\right| \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Then, from the upper bound for $e^x$ established in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), we have

$$\left|\frac{e^{h/n}-1}{h}-\frac1n\right|
\le \frac{h}{n(n-h)} \tag 2$$

for $h<n$.  Taking $h<1$, we find using $(2)$ in $(1)$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}}e^{x/n}\right|&\le h\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{1/2}}e^{x/n}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\right)\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the right-hand side of $(3)$ approaches $0$ as $h\to 0$, we conclude that

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}}e^{x/n}}$$

And we are done!